# Does Mongo ensure isolation when updating single documents?

Tags: mongodb, atomic, isolation

The Mongo documentation on atomicity and isolation is a tad vague and slightly confusing. I have this document structure and I want to ensure mongo will handle updates while isolating updated from different users.

Assume a collection of product discount offers. When a user redeems an offer, the `offers_redeemed` field is incremented. The `max_allowed_redemptions` field controls how many times an offer can be redeemed.

```
{ 
     offer_id: 99,
     description: “Save 25% on Overstock.com…” 
     max_allowed_redemptions: 10,
     offers_redeemed: 3
}
```

I tested this using `findAndModify` and it appears to work by updating the offer only if another redemption would be less than or equal to the max allowed; I want to know if this is the correct way to do it and if this would work in a multi user, sharded environment. Is there a scenario where an update to `offers_redeemed` would force it to exceed `max_allowed_redemptions` ? , obviously, that would corrupt the record so we need to avoid it.

```
db.offer.findAndModify({
   query:{ offer_id: 99, $where: “this.offers_redeemed + 1 <= this.max_allowed_redemptions”},
   update: {$inc: {offers_redeemed: 1},
   new: true })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as the documentation very clearly says

> If you don't need to return the document, you can use Update (which can affect multiple documents, as well).

Second, watch the [Update if Current](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-%22UpdateifCurrent%22) strategy on the atomic page. It clearly shows that if the condition applies then the update happens and nothing can come between the two.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that page in the documentation, but that's a perfect example, thx